# como cargo datos en un Recycler View que está encima de otro Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, studio

soy nuevo desarollando en android studio y necesito su ayuda por favor.

**1.** En un recyclerView (vertical) cargo un `layout con las categorías` existentes, mediante un adaptador.
**2.** Ahora en ese `layout con las categorías`, tengo un recyclerView(horizontal) para cargar las imágenes de los productos que pertenecen a dicha categoría, pero no me cargan las imagenes, igual no estoy seguro si estoy haciendo bien la implementacion.

**En resumen, para que me entiendan y me puedan guiar, hice un deslizable vertical para mostrar el texto las categorías, y en el mismo deslizable, quiero un deslizable horizontal para las imágenes que pertenecen a cada categoría, pero no me da, necesito realmente ayuda con esto, enseguida paso los archivos que tengo.**

[ *El punto 1 ya lo hice, ahora el punto 2. no se como hacerlo.* ]

**Este es mi Activity.**

```
package com.proyecto.app1ts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.trisoft.app1ts.Adaptador.ADListaCategorias;
import com.trisoft.app1ts.Adaptador.ADListaCategoriasMain;
import com.trisoft.app1ts.Presentacion.*;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> categorias;
    ADListaCategoriasMain adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView, productsRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listaCategoriasMain);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        categorias = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ADListaCategoriasMain(this, categorias);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        cargarListaCategorias();
    }

    public void cargarListaCategorias() {
        String urlCategorias = "http://192.168.1.210/webservice/getCategorias.php";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(urlCategorias, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> categoriasObtenidas = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("CategoriaId");
                        String descripcion = jsonObject.getString("CategoriaDes");

                        HashMap<String, String> categoria = new HashMap<>();
                        categoria.put("CategoriaId", String.valueOf(id));
                        categoria.put("CategoriaDes", descripcion);
                        categoriasObtenidas.add(categoria);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al obtener datos de categorías: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                categorias.clear();
                categorias.addAll(categoriasObtenidas);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de conexión al obtener categorías: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

**Este es el layout de mi activity, con el recycler view vertical**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/predeterminado"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="navbar_horizontal_principal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.137">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                android:text="Inicio" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCategoria"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                android:text="Categorias" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                android:text="Ofertas" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                android:text="BestPuntos" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMiCuenta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                android:text="Mi Cuenta" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="presentacion">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="386dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camara1" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="386dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camara2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listaCategoriasMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**En ese layout, cargo este layout para mostrar las categorias, el cual tambien tiene un recycler view (horizontal) para mostrar las imagenes que pertenecen a una categoria**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextViewCategoria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre de la Categoría"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/viewProductsButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text=">"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/productsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Este es el layout para mostrar las imagenes en el recycler view (horizontal)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/camara1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Este es mi adaptador que muestra las categorias:**

```
package com.proyecto.app1ts.Adaptador;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.proyecto.app1ts.R;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ADListaCategoriasMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ADListaCategoriasMain.CategoryViewHolder> {

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> categorias;
    private Context context;
    List<String> imagenes;
    ADListaImagenes_CatMain adapter;

    public ADListaCategoriasMain(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> categorias) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categorias = categorias;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ADListaCategoriasMain.CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_item_categoria_main, parent, false);
        return new CategoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ADListaCategoriasMain.CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        HashMap<String, String> categoria = categorias.get(position);
        String categoriaId = categoria.get("CategoriaId");
        String categoriaDes = categoria.get("CategoriaDes");
        holder.titleTextViewCategoria.setText(categoriaDes);
        String urlApiImagenes = "http://192.168.1.210/webservice/getProductos.php?categoriaId="+categoriaId;

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        holder.productsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ADListaImagenes_CatMain(context, imagenes);

        holder.productsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        cargarImagenes(urlApiImagenes, context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categorias.size();
    }

    public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextViewCategoria;
        RecyclerView productsRecyclerView;

        public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTextViewCategoria = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextViewCategoria);
            productsRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productsRecyclerView);
        }
    }

    private void cargarImagenes(String url, Context context)
    {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                List<String> imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String imagen = jsonObject.getString("Imagen");
                        imagenes.add(imagen);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error de Conexion!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

}
```

**Este es el adaptador con la finalidad de mostrar las imagenes de cada categoria:**

```
package com.proyecto.app1ts.Adaptador;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.proyecto.app1ts.R;


public class ADListaImagenes_CatMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ADListaImagenes_CatMain.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> imagenes;
    Context context;
    public ADListaImagenes_CatMain(Context context, List<String> imagenes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ADListaImagenes_CatMain.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_categoria_imagen, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ADListaImagenes_CatMain.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        for (String imagen : imagenes) {
            String imageUrl = "http://192.168.1.251/webservice/imagenes/" + imagen;
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(holder.productImageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagenes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView productImageView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

.